# How to get started after participating in the presale?

Tags: mining, wallets, security

I participated in the Ethereum presale and have my wallet stored safely in my password manager. Then I stepped away from all things ethereum for a couple years. Now I'm ready to get back into it. I have some questions:

- Is it possible to use my real ether on the frontier release?
- Do I need to convert my wallet in any way for it to work with the frontier release?
- Should I move my ether to a safer wallet or anything while mining on frontier?

Thanks and sorry for the very basic questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome back!

Your wallet is [safe as it is.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/773/42)

To use your Ether, some options, such as using the Geth client or an exchange like Kraken, are covered in: [How do I import my presale wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-import-my-presale-wallet)

For mining, you can use the same address that's currently in your wallet, or you can use a completely different one.  When mining, you're not spending any Ether, so you can use a new address for receiving mining rewards.